# In Angular how can check node version and show message during the npm install if installed version not matched with specifed version

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, package

I am trying to define validation which check the node and cli version with specified version before going to install package.json dependencies.

Example:  Suppose when I started my angular project the node and cli version was 5.2.1 and now they are updated 5.2.6 or 5.3.* but I don't want to run my app on updated version so how can I show alert/error message and exit that user who are going to install the app and there package dependencies

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines

Comment: Angular applications don't run on the server. They run on the browser. There is no Node in the browser.

Comment: @JBNizet Right but can we do check in script of package.json if you have any idea ?